# Paginated query optimization

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, database-performance, sqlperformance

paginated query optimization

It would be a real help if you could give your insight.

I have a query with multiple joins and filter criteria, the result is sorted and finally only 100 records are retrieved. Which shall be more efficient?

Option 1:

```
select * from

( SELECT INTR.col1 AS ID

        FROM INTR, TR, J

        WHERE

            INTR.col1 > ?

            AND ........

            AND ........

            AND ........

        ORDER BY INTR.col1

)

where rownum <= 100;
```

Option 2:

```
SELECT INTR.col1 AS ID

        FROM INTR, TR, J

        WHERE

            INTR.col1 > ?

            AND ........

            AND ........

            AND ........

   AND rownum <= 100;
```

Option 2 will be better choice if we can get rid of sorting and select 100 records as soon we have it. How can I confirm? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Option two is more *preformant* from obvious reason that you need not to *sort*.

The **drawback** (and often the reason why the option one is required) is that the second option provides *non stable results*, i.e. you may get each time different 100 rows event if you data are unchanged.

BTW Oracle can optimize the first option in a way you need not to sort the whole cursor result, but only to find the top N rows and return them sorted.